# Form flag with 3 nodes in a binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

I have a binary tree with nodes colored either in green, white or red. The function returns 1 if it finds a path of three nodes that form the italian flag, 0 otherwise.

This is what I've tried but it gives me segmentation fault.

```
struct node{
 char color;
 struct node* left;
 struct node* right;
 struct node* father;
};

typedef struct node* Node; 

int flag(Node v){

if(v==NULL)
    return 0;

flag(v->left);
flag(v->right);

if(v->color=='W' && v->father->color=='G' && (v->left->color=='R' || v->right->color=='R'))
    return 1;

}
```

EDIT: Thanks to all for answering. This should be the correct version

```
int flag(Node v){

if(v==NULL)
    return 0;

if(v->left && v->father)
    if(v->color=='B' && v->father->color=='V' && v->left->color=='R')
        return 1;

if(v->right&& v->father)
    if(v->color=='B' && v->father->color=='V' && v->right->color=='R')
        return 1;

return flag(v->left) || flag(v->right);


  }
```

Comment: Where is the function calling `flag()`? I suspect you just haven't initialized the `Node v` you pass in

Comment: It is called in main.c . I created a tree and called the function flag on the root of the tree

Comment: Strange, why do you have the parent in the node `struct`? By the way, please provide a [mcve]. For now, your question will be close as "can't reproduce" or "unclear".

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of `main.c` then?

Comment: Typedeffing pointers seems to be a phase everyone goes through, and then abandons as the pain becomes unbearable.

Comment: @molbdnilo *ahum* WinAPI *ahum*

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis That pain *is* unbearable.

Comment: @molbdnilo but sadly, still not abandoned.

Comment: Don't add the answer to your question, it makes no sense. Please [edit], to remove it, and post your **own answer** if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you call `flag` with invalid pointer `v->left` or `v->right`.

Probably you did not initialize with NULL the node fields.

Other problem is that if any of `v->left` or `v->right` is NULL you still try to access `v->left->color` in the last composed condition.

Other error is that you do not explicitly return a value in case that the last combination is false.  If

```
v->color=='W' &&
v->father->color=='G' &&
(v->left->color=='R' || v->right->color=='R')
```

is false, you do not return a value at the end of the function.

Comment: this is just a warning for him to check if he initialized the structure members... he should debug there.

Answer (score 0):

You might have NULL pointers...

```
if(v->color=='W' && v->father->color=='G' && (v->left->color=='R' || v->right->color=='R'))
```

You do not check if `v->left` or `v->right` are NULL before you dereference them. For the root node also `v->father` could be NULL.

You should also add an else part returning 0.

Besides that: 
For which purpose do you call `flag(v->left)` and `flag(v->right)` if you don't care about the return value?

Comment: To iterate all the nodes of the tree. I know that I have to store the return value in a variable, but in this case I wouldn't know how to use it

Comment: Then you should check the return value and if you got a 1 you can stop the function and return 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
int flag(Node v)
{

if(v==NULL)
    return 0;

flag(v->left);  // <<-- this call will return when v->left is NULL
flag(v->right); // <<-- this call will return when v->right is NULL

//so, if you come till here in case 'v' is leaf then (v->left is NULL) and (v->right is NULL)
//but you are accessing them as 'v->left->color'  and 'v->right->color'
//that is accessing 'NULL->color' is bound to break.
if(v->color=='W' && v->father->color=='G' && (v->left->color=='R' || v->right->color=='R'))

return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your comment "if you come till here..." is not true. Also in every other case he gets there after calling `flag()` The recursive call will return and we are back here again.

Comment: if(v==NULL)
    return 0; -- at the end it will correctly access the flags.  The only problem may be that V!=NULL and it's an invalid pointer.